# Group structure of an elliptic curve over a finite field

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves

I'd be interested in a short proof of and a reference (first source, not a textbook as e.g. one of Silverman's monographs) for the following result:

> Let $q$ be a prime power and $C/F_q$ be an elliptic curve. Then there
>   are integers  $m,n \geq 1$ with  $$ C(F_q) \cong \mathbb{Z}_m \times
>  \mathbb{Z}_{mn},~~~ gcd(m,q) =1. $$

Comment: How short do you want the proof to be? L. Washington has a proof in his Elliptic Curve book (Theorem 4.1). It relies on the fact that torsion groups $C[n]$ has at most $n^2$ points, but the fact relies on facts on the degrees of division polynomials, which are also not so easy to prove. I do not know if there is really a "short proof without taking as granted any serious fact on elliptic curves".

Comment: The proof that I know uses the following result: Let $K$ be a field of charakteristic $p \ne 0$,
$C/K$ an elliptic curve and $l \in \mathbb{Z}^{\times}$.
Then
$$
C[l] \cong \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\mathbb{Z_{l'}} \times \mathbb{Z}_{l'}, & \mbox{if} ~C ~\mbox{is supersingular}, \cr
\mathbb{Z}_{l'} \times \mathbb{Z}_{l}, & \mbox{else},
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
where $l' = l \cdot p^{-v_p(l)}$.